# pivot table in excel dynamic coumn titles

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have data in the following form

```
userID course  groupNumber 
===========================
111      A      90 
111      B      89 
234      A      90 
234      B      99 
234      C      67
```

I want to convert it to the following form for using it in other program that require it in the following form

```
userID   course1  group1   course2  group2  course3  group3 
============================================================
111        A        90        B      89
234        A        90        B      99        c        67
```

I am not sure if I can do it using pivot table since I do not know how to label the header of columns as course1 group1 ...and I do not know for sure number of courses and groups but I can estimate it if needed.

can I do this in Ecxel ? please direct me since I am not sure what I should search for in google, is this dynamic pivot table?

I am trying also to do it in sql but I still searching it

Note sorry I could not kwno how to format it properly
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy answer: you should keep the table as is, and use an excel pivot table in the following way:

Columns: GroupNumber
Rows: UserID, Course
Values: COUNT(GroupNumber)

Comment: thank you , I do not think it is correct, what about course ID ?and I do not want count group number there isn't any aggregation required just changing format of file